# How omnipay use for stripe payment gate way

Tags: php, codeigniter, thephpleague

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe  how it is used for codeigniter project or there is any other code for codeigniter project.

Or is that any other code for implementing stripe payment gateway in codeigniter project.
I have searched all but did not get anything kindly help me for implementing stripe for codeigniter,i am new to codeigniter

Comment: As far as I know there is no CodeIgniter-specific version of Omnipay. Just install it using composer as described in the installation instructions. You can require the vendor/autoload.php file from wherever you need it, or you can require it from the top of index.php if you think you might use other composer libraries as well. I'm on my phone so I can't look up specifics but I have definitely installed libs via composer with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would need a CodeIgniter specific version. It's just PHP, so you can just put this directly in your PHP project - regardless of the framework.

If you want to use Composer with CodeIgniter to autoload this project then [here is a tutorial](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter/).

Other than that, maybe just make a config file with any settings you need and pass them into Omnipay with `$this->config->item('foo')`.